# QT5 Problems Opening SerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am trying to open a SerialPort with QT5.5, but the port is always not able to be opened. I am not that familiar with ports and serial, but I can't find any problems with the way I initiated everything. I am using Mac OSX

```
void MainWindow::init_port()
{
    port = new QSerialPort("com4");     //create port

    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite); //open port
    if(!port->isOpen())
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "port error", "Can't open port!");
    }
//    if(serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
//        serial.write("ok*");
    else
    {
        //error
        qDebug() << port->errorString();
    }

    //set port properties
    port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600); //9600 FOR ARDUINO
    port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
}
```

My overall goal is to be communicating with an Arduino microcontroller with a GUI.

Comment: There's no such thing as `com4` on OS X. You have to list the available ports first. On Unices, the ports are simply the filenames within `/dev`, so you might have e.g. `ttyS3` to mean `/dev/ttyS3`, but that device node has to exist. The simplest thing to do is: unplug your device, `ls /dev|sort>f1`, plug your device in, `ls /dev|sort>f2; diff -u f1 f2` and your device node will be shown in the difference. Make sure your code lets the user select the port/device node!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the properties of the port need to be set *before* `open()`:

```
void MainWindow::init_port()
{
    port = new QSerialPort("com4");     //create port

    //set port properties
    port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600); //9600 FOR ARDUINO
    port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);

    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite); //open port
    if(!port->isOpen())
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "port error", "Can't open port!");
    }
    else
    {
        //error
        qDebug() << port->errorString();
    }
}
```

Also check the return value of [`port->open()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#open), and `error()` if the `open()` failed.

> Opens the serial port using OpenMode mode, and then returns true if
>   successful; otherwise returns false and sets an error code which can
>   be obtained by calling the error() method.

Comment: I tried opening after setting the settings, but I still have the same problem. The error code read: "No such file or directory" but I am not sure what that means...

Comment: @ajl123 - And is your Arduino connected to COM4? What return value and error() do you get? Also check your if/else, gives an 'error' in both cases :)

Comment: @ajl123 - _"No such file or directory"_, means "com4" can't be found. Is the port available? Just in case: try "COM4" too. Not sure about Qt or the OS you're on, but in Windows we need _"\\\\.\\COM4"_.

Comment: I am using Macosx. How do you know which com port to use and such?

Comment: @ajl123 - Don't know about Mac, but you can check in Arduino IDE to see what port it is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

After opening a serialPort it's a good idea to sleep for 250 msec before checking to see if the port is open.